# Jackson post-serialization functionality

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I am serializing multiple lists within the same object and would like to call `clear()` on all list after the object has been serialized.

The current approach is to call clear() manually on each list after serialization but I am hoping there is a more robust approach, such as using a custom `JsonSerializer` or perhaps an `AtomicReference`.

I have little experience with `JsonSerializer` and am hoping someone could provide an example that accomplishes this.

```
public class ResetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Collection> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Collection t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        if (t != null) {
            String jsonList = ???; // how do I generate the JSON output of this list with a custom serializer?
            t.clear();
            return jsonList;
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
public class ResetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Collection> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Collection t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        if (t != null) {

            jg.writeStartArray();
            for (Object o: t) {
               jg.writeObject(o);
            }
            jg.writeEndArray();
            t.clear();
       }
    }
}
```

Notice that this method has `void` return type, i.e. it is not expected to return something. It applies the side-effects that are written in the serialized version of the object.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. As for the `writeObjectField(String, Object)`, how I would inherit the name of the field that is being serialized? There are many list that will use this serializer and I imagine specifying a field name could pose problems. It would also limit the serializer to a very specific field. Would `jg.getOutputContext().getCurrentName()` suffice?

Comment: Specify name on each field as `@JsonProperty("nameList")`.

Comment: My question was directed to the line `jg.writeObjectField("jsonList", t)`. Unless `@JsonProperty` overrides the value specified on `writeObjectField()`.

Comment: Right..check the current modification.